# Similar arrays behaving different

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing an app with mongoose and Express, but before using mongoose I was using the standard MongoClient from mongodb. That returned me an array I could use to render my twig view just fine. However, after making the switch, the array from Mongoose is not working like I expected it to, case being that I can't properly select the array's key's values, like in this code example.

With mongoose:

```
router.get('/:page', function (req, res, next) {
    Page.find({'title': req.params.page.toLowerCase()}, function (err, page) {
        if(!Array.length) {
            next(createError(404));
            return;
        }
        res.send(page[0].title);
    });
```

Response is: nothing, blank.
For some reason, if I do `page[0]` or just `page`, it will return me the array like it should.

Without mongoose:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/ezcm', function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let dbo = db.db("ezcm");
        let query = {title: req.params.page.toLowerCase()};
        dbo.collection("pages").find(query).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (!Array.isArray(result) || !result.length) {
                next(createError(404));
                return
            }
            db.close();
        });
    });
```

(ignore the extra bits of unrelated code)
Response: what I was looking for, like `About me` if it was `localhost:3000/about`.

Seems like they are both arrays, but different kinds of arrays? As a beginner, I can't quite distinguish and work with them. Help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `if(!Array.length)` instead of `if (!page || !page.length)`?  `Array.length` has nothing to do with `page` at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh, i changed that already, but as expected no effect with my issue

Comment: What type of object is `page` when you `console.log` it?

Comment: @Houseman object Array

Comment: @MucaP Does the zeroth index exist inside this array? Does it have a title property?

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse(array)` to the result, mongoose loves to handle their objects and arrays differently than the standard JSON.

Comment: Nope, fails: SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 2
    at Object.parse (native)